# Input datetime não tem opção de calendário

Tags: html

No input `date` dá a opção de abrir calendário para seleccionar a data, no `datetime` não tem essa opção.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="datetime" name="DataInicio" id="DataInicio" >

<input type="date" name="DataReserva" id="DataReserva">
```

Como posso resolver o problema?

Comment: Uma forma muito simples de resolver isso, é usando jQuery. Segue algumas referências https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ Espero que resolva.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, o correto seria o `datatime-local`, mesmo assim vai ter limitações que **vai depender do seu navegador**.

É um recurso do HTML5, onde os Browser que tem que se adaptar, não mais como antes rsrsrs, que as linguagem trabalhavam em cima do navegador, agora é ao contrário, os navegadores que tem que acompanhar as linguagens.

Mas creio que nem o **Chrome nem o Firefox** não tenha suporte 100% ainda.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="datetime-local" name="DataInicio" id="DataInicio" >
<input type="date" name="DataReserva" id="DataReserva">
```

Comment: Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#Browser_compatibility), o Chrome >= 20 já tem suporte a `datetime-local` (mas o Firefox, Safari e IE não tem) - inclusive fiz o teste aqui e só funcionou no Chrome mesmo...

Comment: É... só a parte da Hora que é manual ainda, ele carrega só o calendário.

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer isto eu costumo usar jQuery-UI.
Segue abaixo exemplo genérico de uso.

```js
$("#DataInicio").on("click", function() {
  $("#DataInicio").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
  });
});

$("#DataReserva").on("click", function() {
  $("#DataReserva").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">

<input type="text" name="DataInicio" id="DataInicio" >

<input type="text" name="DataReserva" id="DataReserva">
```

Comment: Importante o uso do `placeholder` (do html5) para melhor comunicação com o usuário.